# the difference between the two in the 'non-restrictive' clause?

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns

**what** in the first sentence is a relative pronoun in a 'non-restrictive' clause. My gut feeling is **which** could take the place of what in the sentence. I am not quite sure of my knowledge of the difference between the two in the 'non-restrictive' clause.

> Online environments vary widely in how easily you can save whatever
>   happens there, **what** I call its recordability and preservability.
>   Even though the design, activities, and membership of social media
>   might change over time, the content of what people posted usually
>   remains intact. Email, video, audio, and text messages can be saved.
>   When perfect preservation is possible, time has been suspended.
>   Whenever you want, you can go back to reexamine those events from the
>   past. In other situations, permanency slips between our fingers, even
>   challenging our reality testing about whether something existed at
>   all, as when an email that we seem to remember receiving mysteriously
>   disappears from our inbox. The slightest accidental tap of the finger
>   can send an otherwise everlasting document into nothingness.
>
> [Psychology of the Digital Age: Humans Become Electric](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=T27OCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=Online+environments+vary+widely+in+how+easily+you+can+save+whatever+happens+there,+what+I+call+its+recordability+and+preservability.&source=bl&ots=5gfIF8YYkP&sig=lJB1fUFeerMK5zbYjUXuQjjLnGw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizzMTI5srdAhWLWrwKHf7gAzAQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=Online%20environments%20vary%20widely%20in%20how%20easily%20you%20can%20save%20whatever%20happens%20there%2C%20what%20I%20call%20its%20recordability%20and%20preservability.&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

**What** can't work as a typical *relative* pronoun:

https://www.englishgrammar.org/relative-pronoun/

The phrase '*what I call its recordability and preservability*' is a ***nominal*** relative clause which can work here as a prepositional complement in parallel with the previous clause '**how...**'
Probably, the author's idea was to combine the suggested terms with their definition in one sentence.

> Online environments vary widely **in** *how* easily you can save whatever
>   happens there, (**in**) *what* I call its recordability and preservability.

(not sure if it's OK to omit the repeated 'in')

The version with '**which**' as a relative pronoun is possible, but (as a part of a non-restrictive clause) it would change the emphasis (like: BTW, I call such things recordability and preservability), while the author probably wanted to introduce those terms more clearly:

> Online environments vary widely in what I call *recordability* and
>   *preservability* of whatever happens there (in how easily you can save
>   it).